# SQL Select Where Order by on same function

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code below runs just fine, but it bothers me that it repeats `datediff(month, last_update, @today_date)` in the select, where, and order by.
There must be a better way. 
Needs to be generic SQL.
Suggestions?

```
declare  @today_date as date
declare  @MonthDelay as int
set @today_date = GetDate()
set @MonthDelay = 18

select   @today_date                               as 'Date_Today',
         last_update                               as 'Last_Update',
         datediff(month, last_update, @today_date) as  MonthDelta
from     my_table
where    datediff(month, last_update, @today_date) > @MonthDelay
order by datediff(month, last_update, @today_date) desc
```

Comment: I've added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax.  In general, you should  add the database tag for the database you are using.

Comment: It should be noted that `datediff` is deterministic. Although the expression appears multiple times, if the optimizer is doing its job well, it won't be *evaluating* that expression multiple times (per row).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your query up as a *derived table* (sub-query):

```
select *
from
(
    select   @today_date                               as 'Date_Today',
             last_update                               as 'Last_Update',
             datediff(month, last_update, @today_date) as  MonthDelta
    from     my_table
) dt
where    MonthDelta > @MonthDelay
order by MonthDelta desc
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a lateral join -- that is `apply` in SQL Server:

```
select @today_date as Date_Today,
       t.last_update as Last_Update,
       v.MonthDelta
from my_table t cross apply
     (values (datediff(month, last_update, @today_date) )
     ) v(MonthDelta)
where v.MonthDelta > @MonthDelay
order by v.MonthDelta desc;
```

Note:  Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  First, you don't need them (and you should simply only use characters, letters and underscore in identifiers so you names almost never need to be escaped).  Second, single quotes are how SQL represents strings, not identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query-

```
Declare  @MonthDelay int=18 
Declare  @dif varchar=datediff(month, last_update, @today_date)
select   @today_date as 'Date_Today',
         last_update as 'Last_Update',
         @dif as  MonthDelta
from     my_table
where    @dif>18
order by @dif desc
```

SQL Server 2014